# Scalar Field Theory for Gravity

Tags: general-relativity, classical-field-theory

While reading the book [*Gravitation Foundation and Frontiers*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521882230) by Padmanabhan, I came across the Lagrangian for a scalar theory of gravity. But the coupling term consist of trace of the Energy Momentum Tensor. If we change the coupling term to $F(\phi)T_{ab}T^{ab}$, what prevents it from being a viable theory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we linearize the equations of motion about a $\phi = 0$ background (and assume the usual sort of kinetic term), we will find a non-relativistic limit of something like $\nabla^2 \phi \propto \rho^2$, which is inconsistent with Newtonian gravity.

Comment: What if I take square root over TabTab. Then it reduces to Newtonian gravity.

Comment: @Khushal: You might be able to recover the Newtonian theory in that case;  I can't immediately think of an objection.  However, that doesn't mean that the theory would be viable;  it could fail for other reasons.  In particular, relativistic scalar theories of gravity frequently have trouble describing light-bending, since most of them either have a conformally flat metric or include frame-dependent effects.  If you're interested in this sort of thing, I highly recommend that you read [Clifford Will's review article on the subject.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2014-4)